# How do I print the DDL that is generated by Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

**Given the [lifted/FirstExample.scala](https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/FirstExample.scala) from GitHub, how would I introduce a `println` that would print the generated SQL?**

I have tried to add a line `println(Suppliers.ddl ++ Coffees.ddl)`, but this gives me no more than the following:
    scala.slick.lifted.DDL$$anon$1@acccef1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eventually I found the answer myself.

```
    (Suppliers.ddl ++ Coffees.ddl).createStatements.foreach(println)
```

More info can be found in the ScalaDoc: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.0-RC1/api/#scala.slick.lifted.DDL